# R でhist(x) 関数でヒストグラムを描けない（ 'x' は数値でなければなりません とエラーを返す）

Tags: r

Rで，以下のようなコードで　関数を作り，その結果をヒストグラムにしたいのですが， 'x' は数値でなければなりません とエラーを返してきてうまくいきません．　助けてください．

```
func01 = function(n){
sample1 <- 100
df1 = data.frame()
for(i in 1:n){
sample1 <- sample1+1000
df1 <- rbind(df1, sample1)
}
return(df1)
}
func01(5)
a<-func01(5)
hist(a)
```

Comment: `func01()` でエラーになります。また、内容的に histogram ではなく bar plot の様な気がします。

Comment: すみません，func01()をfunc01(5)に変更しました．これでhistまでのコードは動きます．　histgram を表示したいです（　各BIN　ごとの度数（頻度）を表示させたいです）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aは5行1列のデータフレームですからとりあえず1列目を指定しました。
histとbarplotを表示してみました。

a<-func01(5)
hist(a[,1])
barplot(a[,1])

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]